# Is there a way to limit CPU usage for longs tasks in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, resources

I am using swift to do lots of computing. I am starting a long process in task #1 below. The CPU usage spikes to 100% - 110% for the duration of the task. Is there a way to make the task go longer and slower to prevent the computer from warming up and the fan kicking on?

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {
    // task #1 do something hard
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // task #2 what to do when finished
    }
}
// task #3 what to do immediately
```

I tried various `qos`s, like `.background` and `.userInteractive`, but that didn't make a difference.

If you need to know, in task #1 I am encrypting text, decrypting it, confirming that it worked properly, and repeating this process over thousands of blocks of random data. I want to make sure the encryption and decryption is working 100% without damaging the data.